# database design for voting system

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, redis, database

I need to store votes for items (by id) in a system. I estimate it's gonna have about 5 million votes.
Each vote consists of:

- id of the voted item
- userdata1
- userdata2
- datetime

"userdata" fields will be used to detect cheaters in the end of the voting. During the voting all votes should be registered.

I need to be able to retrieve 2 kinds of information:

- about each 1 minute) how many votes each "id of the voted item" has
- about each 1 hour) how many votes each "id of the voted item" has after applying some filters to "userdata" fields (like both must be unique in a certain datetime interval, or something like that)... I don't wanna need to able to write those filters in form of an SQL query... I want to iterate over all ~5 million votes and create a new table/data structure that will have the result and then return it to the application

INSERTions of votes shouldn't be a big deal (it's about 2 per second, so I guess any DB can handle it pretty well)

I'm leaning toward something like mongoDB because of the "scripting" needed for the iterating over DB and creating a filter. But maybe it can be solved with SQL on a stored procedure, or a key-value (Redis? 5mi votes should fit in less than 2 GBs RAM) DB?

Comment: This question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. It's not a programming question (it's a design question), and it calls for discussion and opinion. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifically mentions discussion-type questions as not being suitable to ask here. I've voted to close it as "not constructive" for that reason.

Comment: It seems to me that the answer falls into the "software tools commonly used by programmers" explained in the FAQ.

Comment: The databases do, but the question itself is inappropriate. Read the FAQ, specifically the section talking about which questions not to ask here. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think a graph DB is what you need.
I can recommend OrientDB (http://www.orientechnologies.com/). It's a very cool and full featured open source graph database. It's written in Java, but you can use different client drivers. The 1.0 stable release is almost there (< 2weeks).
If you want to give it a try you can use it in the cloud for free (http://www.nuvolabase.com/), so you don't need to install and configure it.
It's schema full, schema mixed and schema less, supports graphs, sql, clustering and much more, you have the flexibility to model your data as you want.